# How to filter mdx query in excel data model with value of excel cell?

Tags: excel, filter, cell, mdx, worksheet

I have a Cube called "Cube Material Status" on MSSQL server.
I need to make a query which will get snapshot from it and put it in Excel Data Model table. There is a lot of records in that cube and it is critical to limit number of records which will be loaded (time, size ...).
At the moment there is a mdx query which works but the filter in query is a static date.
I need to make a dynamic filter in that query, i.e. change value in one excel cell (let say Sheet "Check" - cell "$A$1") and refresh Data Model Table with entered date as filter value.

This is a mdx query at the moment:

```sql
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Qty]}
  ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY 
    {(
    [05_WarehouseDate].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [01_Material].[Type].[Type].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [01_Material].[Material].[Material].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [04_Warehouse].[Warehouse].[Warehouse].ALLMEMBERS * 
    )}
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,
  MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
      ({ 
      [05_WarehouseDate].[Date].&[2023-09-13T00:00:00] 
      })
    ON COLUMNS FROM 
      ( 
      SELECT 
        ({
        [01_Material].[Type].&[METAL] 
        })
      ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube Material Status]
      )
    )
  WHERE 
    ( 
    [05_WarehouseDate].[Date].&[2023-09-13T00:00:00] 
    ) 
  CELL PROPERTIES 
    VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE,
    FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

This mdx query will pick up all records which have

`\[01Material\]\[Type\]` equal to `"METAL"` and `\[05_WarehouseDate\].\[Date\]` equal to `"2023-09-13T00:00:00"`.

The question is how to pick up those values from excel cell(s) and refresh query with those new filter values?